# Ackermann's Function

Tags: recursive-algorithms

$A(m,n) = n+1$ if $m=0$
$A(m,n) = A(m-1,1)$ if $n=0$
$A(m,n)= A(m-1,A(m,n-1))$
This function blows off( I mean increases drastically) after a certain point. For example,$ A(2,4) = A(1,A(2,3)) = A(1,A(1,A(2,2))) = A(1,A(1,A(1,A(2,1)))) = 11$ But, $A(4,2) = 2^{65536}-3$ 
I want to find the $20th$ digit of $A(4,5)$ from the rear end. Is there any efficient algorithm for this? I tried to code in Matlab, but for more than 5000 recursions, The program crashes. I was unable to do even $A(4,3)$.

---

My code:

```
function [r] = A(m,n) 
if(m==0)
    r=n+1;
elseif(n==0)
    r=A(m-1,1);
else
    r=A(m-1,A(m,n-1));
end
end
```

As you can see, it's a straight forward algorithm which has the worst case recursions. Can you suggest a better algorithm to implement?

Comment: It might help if you provide your code so that others can improve it or provide suggestions.

Comment: @probablyme Thank you for the suggestion. I am new to the site. Is the way I put my code good enough or is there another way? Thank you

Comment: The 20th digit from the front or the rear?

Comment: @RossMillikan from the rear. Thanks for that.

Comment: We have $A(4,5)=2^{2^{2^{2^{65536}}}}-3$ and you want the leading digit of $A(4,5) \pmod{10^{20}}$  The values of $2^n \pmod {10^{20}}$ have $19$ intro numbers then a cycle of length $4 \cdot 5^{19}$  You are then interested in ${2^{2^{2^{65536}}}} \pmod {4 \cdot 5^{19}}$  Find the length of that cycle and you can strip off another $2$ from the bottom of the stack.

Comment: Verify that the edit is correct. To include code, insert $4$ spaces before each line to give it the correct alignment.

Comment: @probablyme Yes, It's correct. Thank you for helping me out again.

Comment: @RossMillikan I didn't quite understand your statement. How do I fnd the length of that cycle? On a separate note, Matlab cannot take such huge numbers right? Is there any other software where I can try to implement your algorithm?

Comment: I would think Matlab would do them.  Python and Mathematica have arbitrary precision integers, but you still can't do a stack this tall.  The idea is that powers always cycle.  For example, mod 100, the powers of 2 go 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,28,56,12,24,48,96,92,84,68,36,72,44,88,76,52,4  There are two values before we start a cycle of length 20, so if you want 2^n mod 100, you need to know n mod 20.  Th cycle lengths have the nice pattern I indicated for mod 10^k, but I don't know what it is mod 4*5^19

Comment: @RossMillikan That was very helpful. I will try it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to use modular mathematic. The powers of 2 repeat after 19 times in mod. Try to use that.